# C++ Game Accessing separate classes variables

Tags: c++, class, sdl

I've been trying to make a game in C++, using the graphics library SDL 2.0 but I've ran into a problem.

I have two classes User and Enemy. Here are cut down versions of both, just ask and I'll paste the whole thing

```
class User
{
    public:
       //Friends:
       friend class Enemy;


    protected:
    private:
        //The sprite position
        SDL_Rect SpritePos = {10, 100};
};



class Enemy
{
   public:
        //Friends:
        friend class User;

        Enemy();
       int CheckEnemy(SDL_Surface* &ScreenSurface);
       //Loads enemy images
       bool LoadEnemyMedia();

    protected:
    private:
        //Controls the AI movement
        void Movement();

        //Wizard 1's location on screen
        SDL_Rect Wizard1Pos = {50, 70};
};
```

The function Enemy::Movement finds out the location of the sprite and then moves itself accordingly, however it has can't get the current value of Spritepos, only the the value it initializes with, in this case 10. Here's the function Enemy::Movement's code. How can I fix this, bear in mind that the these functions are running in a loop.

```
void Enemy::Movement()
{
    User Player;


    if (Wizard1Pos.x < Player.SpritePos.x)
    {
        Wizard1Pos.x ++;

    }else if (Wizard1Pos.x > Player.SpritePos.x)
    {
        Wizard1Pos.x  --;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Player.SpritePos.x` will return the member `x` of the member `SpritePos` of the variable `Player`

If you only get the initialized value instead of the updated value, you are probably reading from a different copy than you are writing to. Until there is more info on how and where the data is written, I suggest you look into "Reference" and "Pointer".

Edit: I see your real code looks the same as the example, which I had assumed was simplified:

```
void Enemy::Movement()
{
    User Player;
    printf("%u\n", Player.RefTest.x);

    if (Wizard1Pos.x < Player.RefTest.x)
    {
        Wizard1Pos.x ++;
    }else if (Wizard1Pos.x > Player.RefTest.x )
    {
        Wizard1Pos.x  --;
    }
}
```

The line `User Player;` creates a new object of type `User` on the stack, which is then read from. At the end of the `Movement()` function, the stack variable `Player` is deleted. `Player`is never written to.

Creating a variable called `Player` in one place and then creating another variable called `Player` in another place does not in any way link the 2 (exception: global variables). Variable names have no influence on the behaviour of the code.

If you want Movement to refer to an already existing `User` you need to tell the `Movement()` method which Instance of `User` it is referring to. You do this by adding an argument to the method as follows:

```
void Enemy::Movement(const User & someCompletelyArbitraryVariableName)
{
    printf("%u\n", someCompletelyArbitraryVariableName.RefTest.x);

    if (Wizard1Pos.x < someCompletelyArbitraryVariableName.RefTest.x)
    {
        Wizard1Pos.x ++;
    }else if (Wizard1Pos.x > someCompletelyArbitraryVariableName.RefTest.x )
    {
        Wizard1Pos.x  --;
    }
}
```

The `&` tells the program to not make a copy. The `const` tells the program it's not allowed to change anything in `player` from within the `Movement` method. The `const` adds no value beyond preventing silly mistakes, which - as you will learn - is extremely beneficial.

Comment: I have looked into using a reference variable, however it still reads a different value when I print it from a separate class. How can I make sure it's reading the correct copy.

Comment: I need to see more of the code. How about a public dropbox/gdrive/skydrive folder?

Comment: Thanks this has really help, but I still have 2 questions. How do i pass the correct instance of User (What do I pass as a parameter) and when using 'void Movement(const User& Player)' I get the error "User does not have a name type", how can I fix this?

Comment: I guess you wrote that in the header Enemy.h. The header does not know what User may be yet. You need to look up "forward declaration" in a textbook (or google).

Comment: About what to pass as a parameter, you need to decide where you want the `User` instance which you call 'player' to live, and how to control it's lifetime. The project you are attempting is a bit much to start with C++. I recommend spending a few days on tutorials which cover programs that consist of multiple files.